# ACME http2 server error with Traefik

Tags: traefik

I am not sure this is a bug but I have laterally scoured every thread for the past 3 days and I am at my wits end.

I am unable to get ACME working with Traefik in swarm mode.
docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  consul:
    image: consul
    command: agent -server -client='{{ GetInterfaceIP "eth0" }}' -bind='{{ GetInterfaceIP "eth0" }}' -bootstrap
    networks:
      - consul
    volumes:
      - "/srv/www/consul:/data"
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 45s
        monitor: 15s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 10
        window: 60s

  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.5.4
    command: -c --web --logLevel=DEBUG --debug=true
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    networks:
      - traefik_net
      - consul
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /srv/www/certs:/certs/
      - /srv/www/docker/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
```

traefik.toml

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
        address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.https]
        address = ":443"
        [entryPoints.https.tls]

[docker]
    watch = true
    swarmmode = true

[consul]
    endpoint = "consul:8500"
    prefix = "traefik"

[acme]
    email = "myemail@domain.com"
    storage = "traefik/acme/account"
    entryPoint = "https"
    onDemand = false
    OnHostRule = true
    acmeLogging = true
```

The network was created like.

```
docker network create --driver overlay --subnet 10.1.1.0/16 traefik_net
docker network create --driver overlay consul
```

The errors I am getting:

```
level=debug msg="No provided certificate found for domains staging.example.net, get ACME certificate." 
level=debug msg="Looking for an existing ACME challenge for staging.example.net..." 
level=debug msg="No certificate found or generated for staging.example.net" 
level=debug msg="http2: server: error reading preface from client 10.255.0.3:51514: read tcp 10.255.1.47:443->10.255.0.3:51514: read: connection reset by peer"
```

The thing I don't get is the ip's that are showing here are part of the ingress network.

```
"Containers": {
            "4befecaed26dbe9667481b911a03bd6d33cfacfbc48f0a773da60bd82e88c063": {
                "Name": "server_traefik.ibi1uendqffht27anh9109ozk.s87e5ykdm0s8mmmv5jjc0ps64",
                "EndpointID": "377f484f6c038c31a04fc7b02e7cf94a013a8d83916d03b57f8a74463159c1ca",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:ff:01:2f",
                "IPv4Address": "10.255.1.47/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ingress-sbox": {
                "Name": "ingress-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "e83ae16d6be547f3d2141c4d48aec8e0b3a45b0de841e1e155073a5011cbbab9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:ff:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "10.255.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Idez's answer is the correct one.  It makes total sense now and was just an overlooked configuration...

Answer (score 1):

You must configure the ACME challenge:

```
[acme]
  email = "myemail@domain.com"
  storage = "traefik/acme/account"
  entryPoint = "https"
  onDemand = false
  OnHostRule = true
  acmeLogging = true
  [acme.httpChallenge] # <---
    entryPoint = "http"  # <---
```

https://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/configuration/acme/#acmehttpchallenge

Comment: Sorry cannot plus 1.  I am a humble 4 points shy of the 15. Guess I better start using stack overflow more...